# SwiftUI: How to make TextEditor field tabbable on MacOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, focus, swiftui-texteditor

I have a two text fields on my View. I want to be able to tab between them. It is currently writing the tab into the text content.

```
struct MyView: View
{
    @State var field1: String
    @State var field2: String

    var body: some View
    {
         TextEditor(text: $field1)
            .disableAutocorrection(false)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .font(Font.system(size: 22, weight: .medium, design: .default))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .lineLimit(3)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)

        TextEditor(text: $field2)
            .disableAutocorrection(false)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .font(Font.system(size: 22, weight: .medium, design: .default))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .lineLimit(3)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
    }
}
```

How do I make the tab jump to the next field? Do I manually need to manage the focus or is there a simpler way?

Comment: still experimenting, check this https://github.com/kasimok/73799274

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `focusable()` modifier. The `focusable()` modifier makes a view focusable, which means that it can be selected using the tab key. (This I what makes the tab jump to the next field)

Here's an updated version of your code that demonstrates how to make the text fields tabbable:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var field1: String = ""
    @State private var field2: String = ""
    
    @FocusState private var isField1Focused: Bool
    @FocusState private var isField2Focused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $field1)
                .focusable(isField1Focused) { focused in
                    isField1Focused = focused
                }
                .disableAutocorrection(false)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .font(Font.system(size: 22, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(3)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            
            TextEditor(text: $field2)
                .focusable(isField2Focused) { focused in
                    isField2Focused = focused
                }
                .disableAutocorrection(false)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .font(Font.system(size: 22, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(3)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
        }
        .onAppear {
            isField1Focused = true // Set the initial focus to field1
        }
    }
}
```

The two `@FocusState` properties, `isField1Focused` and `isField2Focused` represent the focus state of each text field, And the focusable modifier is applied to each text field, specifying the corresponding `@FocusState` property and updating it when the focus is changed.

`.onAppear` modifier is used to set `isField1Focused` to true, making the first text field active when the view emerges.

If the user presses the Tab key, the focus will automatically move between the text fields, allowing it to switch from one to the other without inserting a tab character into the content.

Comment: Am I being stupid? I cannot find .tabFocus in Xcode or any of Apple's documentation or anything on the web?

Comment: @iphaaw In SwiftUI, you can manage the tab order between text fields by using the ``focusable`` modifier and the ``FocusState API`` introduced in iOS 15 / macOS 12. I think my answer is quite legacy as of now, my apologies. I have edited the answer by creating a ``FocusState`` for each text field, you can control which field receives focus when the user presses the Tab key.

And this should work (hopefully) T_T

Comment: My problem is not selecting the next field, but that the tab types into the TextEditor field and doesn't even reach the focus.

Comment: @iphaaw have you tried just override the ``insertTab(_:)`` method ?